# Why is it 'the Corona virus' not 'Corona Virus'?

Tags: grammar, american-english, articles, proper-nouns

Corona is the **name** of a virus and hence is a proper noun. Please tell me why this exception arises. Also if there are other similar cases when 'the' is used before proper nouns, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen a lot of references to the virus as "corona virus" without the "the".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Corona Virus" is *not* the name of the virus which causes the pandemic disease Covid-19, it is the name for the *type* of virus of which it is an example. This is similar to the way in which "ape" is the *type* of species to which chimpanzees, gorillas, bonobos and humans belong.

The [World Health Organisation](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/technical-guidance/naming-the-coronavirus-disease-(covid-2019)-and-the-virus-that-causes-it) has named the specific virus which is causing the pandemic "SARS-Cov-2". If anyone talked about 'the SARS-Cov2' they would be talking about a specific individual virus, perhaps one that they had under an electron microscope at the time.

There many different corona viruses (which are called corona viruses because they have protruding proteins on their outer surfaces and so appear to have a 'corona' round them under an electron microscope) several of which cause the so-called 'common cold'. We refer to SARS-Cov-2 as "the corona virus" because it is the one we are all talking about at the moment, this distinguishes it from all the others.

We don't talk about different species of ape in this way because we can see and recognise individual apes so "the ape" refers to a specific individual (in my case a human, or 'Naked Ape' as [zoologist Desmond Morris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Ape) called us, named Ben).

We can't see individual viruses, at least not without an electron microscope, so we talk about "the corona virus" referring to the whole species called SARS-Cov-2. This is somewhat similar to the way in which Desmond Morris referred to the entire human species as "The Naked Ape" in his book of the same name when it came out in 1969.

Comment: The WHO has posted 'There is a current outbreak of Coronavirus (COVID-19) disease.... Coronavirus disease (COVID-19) is an infectious disease caused by a newly discovered coronavirus.' [[WHO](https://www.who.int/health-topics/coronavirus#tab=tab_1)] So it refers to the disease as 'Coronavirus disease' (not, as far as I've looked 'Coronavirus' or 'coronavirus') as well as COVID-19. I'd say the capitalisation makes it a proper noun ... with the second word non-capitalised. Contrast 'heart disease'; compare 'Lyme disease'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would say that they might be using the term "Coronavirus disease" without a space between 'Corona' and 'virus'  as a proper noun. However they also say 'a newly discovered coronavirus' which indicates that 'coronavirus' is a term for a group of viruses, not a single one. The fact remains that they have officially named the pandemic disease 'Covid-19' and the virus itself 'SARS-CoV-2'.

Comment: Yes; problems arise where capitalisation of single terms is not the sole alternative in use, where different registers co-exist ('The western lowland gorilla (Gorilla gorilla gorilla) is a subspecies ....'), and where we use compound nouns/polynomials.

Comment: So according to what you are saying, if I want to use a proper noun to pinpoint one specific kind of that when ambiguity arises, I should use the article, _the_. Am I right?

Comment: @AmitKrishnaA That's just about right but I wouldn't take it as a rigid rule. English usage gets very fluid at times, particularly in general conversation, online posts and the news media.